# SAP sapshcut.exe forward slash in fieldname trying to prepopulate

Tags: sap-gui

I am facing a problem with `sapshcut.exe`.

**What I want to achieve**

Basically, I want to generate Links in an Reporting System which opens a specific SAP transaction and prepopulate fields.

**The Plan**

I found the SAP Shortcut Tools which does exactly what I try to achieve. With `sapshcut.exe` I can open an SAP connection, start a transaction and can prepopulate fields. That is working great for standard transaction. Example (in brackets [] I have removed my own data due to secret information), all in one line:

```
C:\"Program Files (x86)"\SAP\FrontEnd\SapGui\sapshcut -user="%username%" -language="DE"
-system="[system]" -client=[xxx] -type=transaction
-command="[transaction] [structure]-[fieldname]=value;"
```

**The Issue**

The transaction I start is a custom transaction in an own namespace which includes forward slashes e.g. /yxz/xxxxxxx. And also the fields are in the same namespace /xx/xxxxx-xxxxx. 
To build up the `sapshcut.exe` string it looks like this:

```
C:\"Program Files (x86)"\SAP\FrontEnd\SapGui\sapshcut -user="%username%" -language="DE"
-system="[system]" -client=[xxx] -type=transaction 
-command="/[namespace]/[transaction] /[namespace]/[structure]-[fieldname]=value;"
```

Somehow this is not executed correctly. Instead of opening the transaction, SAP is only starting a GUI Information view. Without the field, the transaction is opened correctly. It is definitely the forward slash from the namespace of the field which is causing the issue. I have also tried to execute the opening of the transaction and the population of the field in the SAP Command field which works fine:

```
/n/[namespace]/[transaction] /[namespace]/[structure]-[fieldname]=value
```

**-edit-Additional Information-** 
After additional try&error I found that this is related to our namespace starting with "v" which means this results in /v*** which starts the GUI information screen like the option -version. so I search for escaping this somehow. 
**-end edit-**

I have tried different escape signs e.g. / ' etc. which results in opening the transaction in SAP but not populating the field.

Also, I did activate the trace with the command "-trace=3" but cannot see any issues in the tracefile.

Has anyone of you a solution for this? Unfortunately, I cannot change the namespace.

Comment: for me `"C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SapGui\sapshcut.exe" -maxgui -user= -pw= -system= -client= -type=transaction -command="ZZZ43 /YGREK/YGREK=12345"` works like a charm in CMD. Something is wrong with your setup

Comment: Strange, I will try other custom transaction and see if it is this one specific transaction which has this issue.

Comment: maybe this transaction has some validation on the field and doesn't accept your value

Comment: So first it does apply for other custom transactions as well. What do you mean by input validation exactly? I can write regular in field and see no specific check.

Comment: I mean [this](https://www.sapnuts.com/courses/core-abap/classical-reports/selection-screen-event.html). Field validation can be done in different ways, and if in your transaction it is implemented in some weird way, it can interfere with automatic filling. However, in my opinion, it is highly improbable. But so far I have no other ideas

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. If i enter a wrong value ent press enter only the field with wrong data remains active and a error is shown. this is what i think you mean. what I find strange is that when I use the comand field it works including population of the field, with sapshcut the gui information is shown.

Comment: So after more try & error, our namespace starts with v. and /v seems to trigger the gui version window. Any chance to escape this somehow?

Comment: And what happens with a leaging `/n`, the same way as you did directly in the command field: `-command="/n/[namespace]/[transaction] /[namespace]/[structure]-[fieldname]=value;"` ?

Comment: Hi Sandra, adding a leading `/n` in the command part of sapshcut.exe call results in an SAP GUI error window saying something like (translated by me) "Not all Data for SAP-GUI-Link available. Systemdescription and GUI-Startparameter unknown. Please add missing Data." I do belive that `/n` is not valid here and this is done via parameter `-reuse=0` or `-reuse=1`

Comment: `our namespace starts with v. and /v seems to trigger the gui version` unlikely this is the reason. I tried firing the tcode starting with `/VSPACE/VTCODE` and it worked fine. V-starting screen field will not conflict with version param either

Comment: Your path to `sapshcut.exe` is weird (double quotes in the middle): `C:\"Program Files (x86)"\SAP\FrontEnd\SapGui\sapshcut`. Do as shown by Suncatcher.

Comment: First I like to thank you for looking with me into the issue.

Comment: Hi Sandra, I have removed the quotes as suggested  and receive the error ´The Program cannot be found....´ I have also seen in the trace file of ´sapshcut.exe´ that the command is correctly passed.

Comment: I run out of ideas. It seems not possible with that namespace.....as standard transactions work like a charme using 'sapshcut.exe'

Comment: This message to let you know that I reproduced your symptom exactly as you said with 7.60 PL1. It works for `-cmd="/ATL/KP02 /ATL/KPKUPAT-ZKPNO=TEST; T001-WAERS=EUR"` but fails/does what you say for `-cmd="ZZTEST /VTEST/FIELD=HELLO;"`. Weird. It must be a bug. Either contact the SAP support or use the workaround I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do extensive tests and it must be a bug when you have a field with namespace starting with `/V` (and preceded with a space).

As a workaround, I could make it work with the following command (presented as 3 lines here but must be on one line when you execute it), by using a fake parameter before each `/V` field with `;` between, and **without space before `/V...`** (below `DUMMY=DUMMY;/VTEST/FIELD=HELLO`):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SapGui\sapshcut.exe" -user="myuser" -pw="mypw"
-language="EN" -system="DEV" -client="100" -type=transaction 
-cmd="ZZTEST DUMMY=DUMMY;/VTEST/FIELD=HELLO; /ATEST/FIELD=WORLD;"
```

(*) NB:
I think it's a bug because:

1. If I enter directly this string preceded with `/N` in the SAP GUI Command Field and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it works correctly:

   ```
   /NZZTEST /VTEST/FIELD=HELLO;
   ```
2. But with `sapshcut.exe` this command displays the version popup/is buggy (NB: with `sapshcut.exe`, the command must never be preceded with `/N`):

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SapGui\sapshcut.exe" -user="myuser" -pw="mypw" 
   -language="EN" -system="DEV" -client="100" -type=transaction 
   -cmd="ZZTEST /VTEST/FIELD=HELLO;"
   ```

I have this version of SAP GUI for Windows:

```
MAIN MODULE INFORMATION:
   sapfront.dll
   SAP Frontend for Windows
   760 Final Release
   7600.1.0.3384
   1902768
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your investigation. Unfortunately I couldn't make it work with the workaround. The DUMMY value doesn't make it skip the /V command. I will ask our IT Department to open up a OSS Ticket. Thank you very much to all of you.

Comment: What is important in the workaround is to **not include a space** before `/V.../FIELD`, put it right after `;` without space. Apart this, informing SAP support is the right thing to do.

Comment: You are right, deleting the space did the trick :-D. You make me happy. Thanks!